# Video control in a tampermonkey script with JQuery

Tags: jquery, web, tampermonkey

I'm woring on a tampermonkey script that adds elements to the page in the syntax

```
<div class="dplayer-setting-speed-item" data-speed="10"><span class="dplayer-label">10</span></div>
```

However, when I'm trying to bind a event handler to it like

```
            $('.dplayer-setting-speed-item').on('click',()=>{
            var r=$(this).attr('data-speed');
            console.log(this);
            console.log(r);
            $('video')[0].playbackRate=r;
        });
```

it does nothing and prints two 'undefined' for my two console.log().
How to solve it?

Comment: Does it work if you just use `$('.dplayer-setting-speed-item')` again instead of `$(this)`?

Comment: Well it works but I am only able to register a handler for only one of them...